# React Typescript: Ant Design Alert not rendering

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, antd

I have an Array `messages` and try to render different `Alert` if the Status is true but it dont render in the Browser.
`Console.log(message)` has shown that the `message` is not empty.

```
return (
   <Space direction="vertical" >
      {messages.map(item => {
         item.status ?
            <Alert
               message={item.title}
               description={item.statusMessage}
               type="success"
               showIcon
            /> :
            <Alert
               message={item.title}
               description={item.statusMessage}
               type="error"
               showIcon
            />
      })}
   </Space>
);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please bear in mind that this `map()` function will not return anything, because its content is in curly brackets `{}` and not parentheses `()`. You could also use `return item.status ? ...`.